# How to remove default filter by store (Purchase Point) in sales_order_grid.xml in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

In magento report sales_order_grid.xml has filter by store_id.

```
<filters name="listing_filters">
            <filterSelect name="store_id" provider="${ $.parentName }">
                <settings>
                    <options class="Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store\Options"/>
                    <caption translate="true">All Store Views</caption>
                    <label translate="true">Purchase Point</label>
                    <dataScope>store_id</dataScope>
                    <imports>
                        <link name="visible">ns = ${ $.ns }, componentType = column, index = ${ $.index }:visible</link>
                    </imports>
                </settings>
            </filterSelect>
        </filters>
```

I want to remove this filter. How to do that?
If can not remove this filter. Can I add css class or style for this filter to display none it?

Please help me,
Thank you so much,
BienHV

Comment: Do you want to remove from order grid?

Comment: I want remove filter select in filter tab. When user click FIlter button it show many type for the user filter. I want to remove filter by Purchase Point. I don't want the user filter by that. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but I had the same requirement and wasn't able to found an answer. Here is how to do it :

Just create **sales_order_grid.xml** with the following content : (this is the `<visible>false</visible>` which does it)

```
<!--app/code/FolderA/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <filterSelect name="store_id">
                <settings>
                    <visible>false</visible>
                </settings>
            </filterSelect>
        </filters>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```